# ConstraintLayout - Behavior of match_constraint with only one side constrained

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I was doing some experimentation by constraining, for example, only the right and top side of on element, and then setting, then setting the `width` to `match_constraint` and the `height` to `wrap_content`.

In this case, what `match_constraint` does is really strange to me. It seems to work as a `wrap_content` that never lowers the width, it only increases.

Is it okay to use `match_constriant` in this scenario? Does it even make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a dimension is set to `MATCH_CONSTRAINT`, the default behavior is to have the resulting size take all the available space. <sup>[read more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)</sup>

In your case you are not defining the available space as device width or something what you expected. To make `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` work, you must define left and right constraints for width, and top bottom contarinst for height if needed.

> Is it okay to use match_constriant in this scenario? Does it even make sense?

No, you should use wrap-content in this case.